# Lighthouse complains about improperly sized images

Tags: html, web, lighthouse

Lighthouse throws me an error - "Properly size images".

```
<picture>
    <source 
        srcset="//localhost:3000/addons/website-public/img/landing-route-planning/last_mile_route_planning_software-mobile.webp 1x, 
                //localhost:3000/addons/website-public/img/landing-route-planning/last_mile_route_planning_software-mobile@2x.webp 1.1x" 
        sizes="auto" 
        type="image/webp">
    <img 
        srcset="//localhost:3000/addons/website-public/img/landing-route-planning/last_mile_route_planning_software-mobile.webp 1x, 
                //localhost:3000/addons/website-public/img/landing-route-planning/last_mile_route_planning_software-mobile@2x.webp 1.1x" 
        src="//localhost:3000/addons/website-public/img/landing-route-planning/last_mile_route_planning_software-mobile.webp" 
        sizes="auto"  
        width="718" 
        height="531" 
        style="max-width: 718px; width: 100%; height: auto;" 
        fetchpriority="high">
</picture>
```

But as you can see, it uses 2x dpi images only if device got such dpi, but when i'm running lighthouse tests, it complains about it.

2x DPI real image resolution is **860 × 636**
1x DPI is **430 × 318**

I've tried removing 1.1x from srcset, then error's gone. But i need these 2x DPI images for retina displays, because otherwise they would be looking awfully on them.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Lighthouse check for properly sized images is triggered whenever the rendered size is at least 4 KiB smaller than the downloaded version of the image. What happens here is that the original image is resized to the resolution of the rendered image, than file sizes get compared.

What you need to know is that the Google Lighthouse Audit uses a width of 412px for the mobile audit and the width of the current window for the desktop audit.

So for the mobile audit the images will be resized to 100% of the viewport based on your CSS (`style="max-width: 718px; width: 100%; height: auto;"`) which should result in resolutions of 305x412 px or 824x609 px.

For the desktop audit the max-width is limited to 718 px based on your CSS. For large resolutions browsers should download the 860 × 636 px variant, which should result in a rendered resolution of 728x538 px.

So for both mobile and desktop it is very likely that the images in your srcset are not optimal and therefore trigger the check.

To fullfill the requirements of the audit you can change the resolution of your original images or add more resolutions so the image downloaded by the browser can be a better fit.